# Error when storing JSON after an ajax request (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm quite new to JavaScript/jQuery so please bear with. I have been trying to store the resulting JSON after an ajax request so I can use the login info from it later in my program. I get an error stating that "Data" is undefined. Here is the problematic code:

```
function LOGIN(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://.......&JSONP=Data&.........',
        success: function Success(){
            var SessionData = Data();
            (FunctionThatParsesJSON);
            }
        })
}
```

I have checked the URL manually and it works fine (including) being wrapped in the "Data" function. From what I have found online, this may be something to do with ajax been asynchronous. Can anyone suggest a way of storing the JSON so that I can use it later?

Comment: Well, where *is* `Data` defined? JQuery passes the response to the the success handler,

Comment: As for the part where it having to do with the ajax being async, that's not an issue here since your success callback is being called. You might change the Success() function to take a parameter and then use it instead of the Data(); call. 

What server language do you use?

Comment: The returned data should be is the success callback `success: function(data){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following;

```
function LOGIN(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://.......&JSONP=Data&.........',
        success: function Success(data){
            functionToProcessData(data)
        })
}
```

When making your ajax call, you can handle the response given by assigning a parameter to the function. In the case above, I have passed the 'data' parameter to the success function allowing me to then use it in further functions (as demonstrated by 'functionToProcessData(data)'.

Answer (score 0):

The response from ajax call is captured in success handler, in this case 'data'.
Check below code:

```
    success: function(data){
        var SessionData = data.VariableName;  
          // Here goes the remaining code.
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since people ask about explanation, thus putting few words:

When we do $.ajax, javascript does the async ajax call to the URL to fetch the data from server. We can provide callback function to the "success" property of the $.ajax. When your ajax request completed successfully, it will invoke registered success callback function. The first parameter to this function will be data came from server as response to your request.

```
success: function ( data ) {
    console.log( data );
},
```

Hope this helps.

Internally everything uses promises. You can explore more on promises:
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using JSONP, so your code should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://.......&JSONP=Data&.........',
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success: function (data){
        (no need to parse data);
    }
});
```

Another option:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://.......&JSONP=Data&.........',
    dataType:"jsonp"
})
.done(function (data){
    (no need to parse data);
});
```

[See the documentation and examples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
```

these are the arguments which get passed to the success function. data would be the json returned.

Comment: Code may be useful but an **explanation** is more helpful. The OP said he is a beginner, so just throwing code at them probably doesn't help them much.

Comment: Sorry, I'll explain better next time.